# how to deploy angular app with the sub pages into external server

Tags: angular, deployment, angular-ui-router, web-deployment

I have a simple angular application with several components, and i want to serve it into my external server in internet, the app work with my local server by command `ng serve` but when i publish it with command `ng build --prod` it is create a single html file, and when i store all create file of this `ng build --prod` into my root directory of server, the server just know my first page and when i click to for ex going to another page i have a error of 404 (not page found).

my question is how to solve this problem, thanks

app.component.html:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav"
    fixedInViewport="true"
    [attr.role]="isHandset ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
    [mode]="(isHandset | async)!.matches ? 'over' : 'side'"
    [opened]="!(isHandset | async)!.matches">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="/about-me">About Me</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="/second-page">Projects</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="/third-page">Contact</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="(isHandset | async)!.matches">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

app.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'about-me', component: AboutMeComponent},
  { path: 'second-page', component: SecondPageComponent},
  { path: 'third-page', component: ThirdPageComponent}
];
```

Comment: Have a look at the guide on the Angular site, there is a section about server configuration: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Answer (score 1):

Your local server is normally under root of the server address, ex. `http://localhost:xxxx`. But when you host it on the remote server, you might not deploy it under a root folder as `http://mywebsite.com`, instead you might have it under `http://mywebsite.com/myapp/`.

If that is the case, you need to set one thing in your `index.html`,

```
<base href="/myapp/">
```

or run

```
ng build --base-href /myapp/
```

Comment: it is works, but my question is when i am switch to another page i have error 404 , for ex: http://mywebsite.com/second-page

Comment: Get the same issue, because in my backend (express Router) I use : `router.get("*"){ ... }` to handle the request.
How to manage it?

Comment: I see, then another answer about `RewriteEngine` is the answer, basically, you want to wire every http call to `index.html` on your hosting server.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html